# Router API cannot use res.end() or res.json() in catch/

Tags: rest, next.js

I dont know why but if function not get error, it work perfectly , but when it get error, catch always display

```
res.end is not a function
```

it like i can't use res in catch, but in try res still work, Am i missing something?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";

const handler = async (res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
  axios({
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      url:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? "https://.../refresh_token"
          : "http://localhost:4000/refresh_token",
      withCredentials: true,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=180000");
        res.end(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.end(JSON.stringify((error as Error).message));
        resolve(); 
      });
  });
};

export default handler;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in your `handler` function should be a `NextApiRequest` object, not a `NextApiResponse` object:

```js
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => { //...
```

Since `req` is expected to be the first parameter, passing `res` there will mean calling `end` on the `NextApiRequest` object — an error because `end` doesn't exist there.